# Is it possible to search for a keylogger using netstat / nmap?

Tags: nmap

I read on website (http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/security#firewallantivirus) the following phrase:
"By default, Ubuntu ships with no open ports on public interfaces."

1. Does that mean that if I got infected by a keylogger my computer would not send information to the hacker's computer?
2. Is it possible to download an application (virus/malware) that would open a port on public interface if it had root access?
3. How do I check for open ports on public interfaces? I know netstat -a, netstat, nmap -v localhost, nmap -v -p1-65535 localhost, but they all show different information so I am not sure.
4. Using nmap -v -p1-65535 localhost my computer finds two ports:
   Discovered open port 631/tcp on 127.0.0.1
   Discovered open port 51072/tcp on 127.0.0.1
   Does the IP at the end mean that it's not being sent to another computer?

Sorry for asking so much questions, I have been reading about this subject in two different languages for two days and I still can't answer those.

Comment: Netstat helps with 'open ports', but that won't help you to ID a keylogger necessarily.  Traffic analysis on the network, and deep packet analysis, tend to be more useful in tracking and identiifying keyloggers.  If you're concerned about a keylogger being on your system, then reformat your computer.

Answer (score 2):

> By default, Ubuntu ships with no open ports on public interfaces.

Not entirely true. Technically speaking, Ubuntu ships with minimum open ports, particularly 631, which is for network printing. But such services as mail transfer, ssh, ftp - they all require a server software installed on your machine. For instance , `ssh` port 22 is open on my machine only after I installed `openssh-server`.

That doesn't mean you're 100% safe, only 89% safe. The other 10%  can be added by enabling the default firewall or installing your own.

> Does that mean that if I got infected by a keylogger my computer would not send information to the hacker's computer?

I am no information security professional, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were keyloggers that send information through port 80, which is the standard port for internet stuff. Browsers do that, for instance. So the answer is , information could still escape your computer

> Is it possible to download an application (virus/malware) that would open a port on public interface if it had root access?

Yes. As I described a little earlier if you install `ftp` or `ssh` servers, you get ports 25 and 22 open, and you install them as root; So what stops malware doing the same if it has root access ? Exactly nothing.

> How do I check for open ports on public interfaces? I know netstat -a, netstat, nmap -v localhost, nmap -v -p1-65535 localhost, but they all show different information so I am not sure.

`netstat` and `nmap` are two of the basic and best command-line utilities that are used by system administrators across the world. They're already good, but require learning a bit about the flags.

`netstat -tulpan` is what I personally use in my checks. This shows all TCP and UDP connections, including listening ones and prints out the connections in ip address (numeric ) format. If there's an IP address that is suspicious , it can be checked with `nslookup` or `dig` or `whois`. In addition the `-p`flag will tell you what program is using which port or has connection established. That is pretty useful, you can later lookup that process as well as process id, eventually locating the executable file.

`nmap` is good for scanning local network as well as your own machine. Personally I use `sudo nmap -sT -T4 -n 192.168.0.1/24` on my local network to check pretty quickly all the devices on my network, including my own machine. I can see what computers are on the network.

> Using nmap -v -p1-65535 localhost my computer finds two ports: Discovered open port 631/tcp on 127.0.0.1 Discovered open port 51072/tcp on 127.0.0.1 Does the IP at the end mean that it's not being sent to another computer?

When you scan with localhost , that means you're scanning your own computer. Localhost,or the address that computer refers to itself, is set to `127.0.0.1`. It's like asking yourself `Who am I` ? Well, `I am me` would be the response.

That means you have ports 51072  and 631 open. 631 is open by default, but 51072 is a little trickier. Ports from 1024 to 65534 are used to establish temporary connections, for example by internet browsers. Typically they're opened and then closed, but if it's persistent you may already have some form of malware installed, not necessarily a keylogger.

I'd suggest you disconnect the computer from the network immediately. Examine your Autostart entries, change password with `sudo passwd $USER`, enable Ubuntu's default firewall with `sudo sed -i 's;ENABLED=no;ENABLED=yes;g' /etc/ufw/ufw.conf`. Make sure you change/enable the router admin password (not the wifi password, the actual password that allows you make settings changes to your router), preferably from another computer.

After that you should be able to return to your internet browsing, but you may want to observe your connections, ports, behavior of the machine. Avoid doing anything that could compromise important passwords and logins. If you still have an issue, consider asking information security professionals for help.

Comment: also, for the first question, that doesn't address *outgoing* traffic

Answer (score 0):

1. No; if your machine doesn't have any open ports, that just makes infection harder in the first place. If you have malware on your machine, it most likely beacons out, which is rarely stopped.
2. Malware opening ports isn't that common against clients. They often sit behind a NAT firewall, so (as long as they don't have uPnP enabled) even if they had a port open, only the local network can communicate with them.
3. As Serg said, `netstat -tulpan` is your friend for seeing what traffic is going on. Try running from a console rather than a GUI (switch from the GUI login with `Ctrl-Alt-F1`), and then work up to a GUI, slowly starting your normal programmes so you can identify when connections are starting.
4. Anything bound to `127.0.0.1` is internal, and not accessible to anything other than your device. TCP 631 is the printer service, and TCP 51072 is an [Ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), just waiting for a response. `netstat -tulpan` will help you identify the process using that port. These aren't anything particularly suspicious.